# Azure Logic Apps: Set condition to False when SQL query returns no rows of data

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

How can i conditionally test the output from an Execute SQL Query to make sure it returns some rows of data.

In my example below if the query returns no rows I don't want it to send an email, I want to do something else. What is the test?

[image: What do i put here]

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I test, if it queries result is no rows, the query body will be like this:

```
{
  "OutputParameters": {},
  "ResultSets": {}
}
```

So you could add a Condition with `@{body('Execute_a_SQL_query')['OutputParameters']}` is equal to `{}`. If true, do the things you want. Yo could set this in the `Code view` mode.

[image]

The below is the test result, hope this is what you want.

[image]

Comment: I would test 'ResultSets'  equals '{}'? I guess it will give the same thing but...

Comment: Thank you George that has worked for me, and extra mention to Thomas's comment as if you use result sets then that's already defined by the logic app so don't have to write it manually :)

Answer (score 3):

This will work in Query SQL V2.
What is does is takes the ResultSet and converts to string. This prevent s a null error on the length function. As an empty result set is {}, the length is 2. So if the length is 2 then the the result is empty.

```html
 "expression": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "equals": [
                                "@length(string(body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['ResultSets']))",
                                2
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using similar to this in an until condition which runs until the length is zero. I guess you could do the same?

`@equals(length(body('Execute_a_SQL_query')?['value']), 0)`