# azure logic app - check if stored procedure results are empty

Tags: azure-logic-apps

In an Azure Logic App, I am running EXECUTE STORED PROCEDURE (V2), which I want to check results if there is no returned data.  Below is the result body when no results come back.  How can I check for this in the logic app?

I have tried [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56474796/azure-logic-apps-set-condition-to-false-when-sql-query-returns-no-rows-of-data) but still not working.

[image: screenshot]

update... so I made a string variable, and then appended the results of sql to this string variable.  Then I count the length, if its 2 then the results are blank, if its NOT 2, then it has data.

Is this an efficient way or is there something easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could add a Condition with **"@{body('Execute_stored_procedure_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1']}"** is equal to **"[]"**. If true[means no records], do the things you want. We could set this in the **Code view mode**.

***Example :***

if the SP results some rows, the query body will be like this:

```
{
  "ResultSets": {
    "Table1": [
      {
        "s_no": 1
      },
      {
        "s_no": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  "ReturnCode": 0,
  "OutputParameters": {}
}
```

The sample sp logic with the resultset for the above sample is:
[image]

if the SP results no row, the query body will be like below:

```
{
  "ResultSets": {
    "Table1": []
  },
  "ReturnCode": 0,
  "OutputParameters": {}
}
```

The sample sp logic with no resultset for the above sample is:
[image]

The above SP used and pics are just for easy understanding.

**Logic app's code view** - ***expression*** will be like below:

```
        "expression": {
            "and": [
                {
                    "equals": [
                        "@{body('Execute_stored_procedure_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1']}",
                        "[]"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: thank you!.. this way worked and seems much more efficient than what I had.   much appreciated!

Comment: @solarissf, I'm glad it helped!